# ie6 page style problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

Page is [here](http://cloudpeople.com.au/demo/)

Please enlighten me on how to fix this...

I know [Dean Edwards' IE7 javascript](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), but it might be overkill, is there a simple fix just for my problem?

I tried:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/css/ie6.css" media="all">
<![else]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/css/common.css" media="all">
<![endif]-->
```

But it doesn't work, so i replaced it with:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
...
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Currently I'm still having problems with the second level menu, i.e. [here](http://cloudpeople.com.au/demo/cloud_datacentre/overview)

Comment: IE6 ought to be banished from the face of the earth - **[UPGRADE!](http://www.ie6nomore.com/)**

Comment: Upgrading will only remove the ability for a developer to test and fix the site for their customers and potential customers who are still stuck on IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Miranda: To fix your menu in IE6, update the following rules in your CSS like so --

```
.menuArea ul {
    height: 38px;
    width: 790px;
}

.menuArea ul li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height:2.7em;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.menuArea ul li a {
    color: #383838;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 38px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I suggest you use [conditional-comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for IE6 if you start to notice that any styles you update/define to make the page work for it start to negatively affect it in other browsers. Create a `ie6.css` file and use the conditional-comment below your main CSS file like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" media="all">
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `float:left` to your css may solve the problem.

```
.menuArea ul li a{
     float: left;
}
```

This was tested.

Comment: Note: as marc_s commented IE6 will be banished see also here http://ie6countdown.com/. But Win2k and below cannot upgrade to higher IE version http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer#OS_compatibility.